# Google Colab Runtime dies when using AutoKeras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, kaggle

The Google Colab runtime dies each time i try to run this very basic code that I have copied from the very first example on the AutoKeras.com examples page.

The link to my notebook is:
[Test Code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-iqEqW2qxBo1CtFAWHZiNYBz32Ew7PO8)

Here is the code:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from autokeras.image_classifier import ImageClassifier

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

    clf = ImageClassifier(verbose=True)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train, time_limit=12 * 60 * 60)
    clf.final_fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, retrain=True)
    y = clf.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    print(y)
```

The code, on running, goes until

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Downloading data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz
11493376/11490434 [==============================] - 2s 0us/step
Initializing search.
Initialization finished.
Training model  0
```

And then the runtime dies. This is irrespective of whether GPU is included or the runtime is CPU only.

ETA: The same behaviour is observed on Kaggle, where the kernel dies at the same point.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in Cloud Datalab

Comment: actually I think that even you train it locally, if any error happens, the whole jupyter notebook shut down